# Insert table in new Excel worksheet .net using C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

The below written code working fine for insert a table and  its value in Already existing excel file(D:\MySamplefile.xls).

```
private void WriteToExcel()
{
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=D:\\MySamplefile.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    using (OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = Connection;
            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [EMPLOYEE](EmpFirstName Char(100), EmpLastName char(100), EmpDept char(250))";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //Add values to the table (EMPTable) in the Worksheet
        string strSql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, [EmpDept]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        using (OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, Connection))
        {
            dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmpFirstName", "xyz");
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmpLastName", "abc");
            dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[EmpDept]", "pqr");
            dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }   
}
```

My requirement is that, I need to write the same thing on a newly created excel worksheet, which not saved any where.For new excel doc creation code given below.

```
    public void createExcelDoc( int rowHeight,int sizeCol1, int sizeCol2)
{
        app = new Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        worksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 5;
        worksheet.Rows.RowHeight = rowHeight;               
        worksheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth = sizeCol1;
        worksheet.Columns[3].ColumnWidth = sizeCol2;                
        workbook.Windows.Application.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;            
}
```

I need to replace connectionString in WriteToExcel() method `Data Source=D:\\MySamplefile.xls;` to some thing else. I have no idea.

Comment: Hi there. I made a number of corrections to your post, particularly in relation to begging for urgency. Since you have rolled that back, I have downvoted, and if you do it again I'll flag the question for a moderator. Requests for urgency do not belong in posts, because questions so marked are not more important than the others.

Comment: I do try to be nice to beginners, but equally one does need to speak plainly where the site guidelines, or the spirit of them, are not followed. I agree that it is good if people explain why they downvote, and not everyone does that - I certainly try to. In relation to using rollbacks, you should only use that if the new edit changes the meaning of your post, or you are sure your version is correct - since neither was true here, it was not appropriate.

Comment: Note that it is quite normal for some people to help answer questions, and for some people to just edit and improve posts. I do a lot of the latter these days - I think it is an important contribution to the quality of the site.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to Excel via OleDb, just like with Access.  Connection string examples can be found here:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

For clarity, an old (.xls) file would look like this:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    @"Data Source=D:\MySamplefile.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```

HOWEVER, it this does seem a little overkill for what your method is doing.  Where is the data coming from what you're inserting into Excel?  There may be better (and simpler) ways to do this.